# how to make a vbscript do something when a program is open

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt, msgbox

So What I need is for when `cmd.exe` is open run a `MsgBox` and close `cmd.exe`
such as:

```
' Code for when cmd.exe loads
MsgBox("Command Prompt Disabled")
' closes command prompt
```

Thanks!

> ## *I need actual code*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a vbscript to do this.... use a GPO.. because if someone disables that script your security control is broken.

If you're editing for a single user/single machine...

It might be faster to write a registry vb script or batch file with your control instead of using a GPO for each user you don't want using it. Create the system key if system does not exist in the Windows Key. The Caveat, is you have other controls that won't prevent disabling this with about 5-minutes of Google Searching.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" /t REG_DWORD /v DisableCmd /d 2
```

**Using Gpedit or OU-Level assigned policies for Non-Admins**

```
User configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Prevent access to the command prompt
```

**Other policies to consider adding to Non-Admin User groups.**

```
User configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Prevent access to registry editing tools
User configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Don't run specified Windows Applications
```